# Scylla add new DC - Waiting long time and existing DC stuck

Tags: scylla

I have problems on running production scylla.  Nodetool status output show like this

```
Datacenter: dc1
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address          Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.0.0.43   277.23 GB  256          ?       40bdas292a3-ed2a-2983hjsdp23213-asd212  Rack1
UN  192.0.0.44  274.51 GB  256          ?       e0f2as2e892-e0b7-2983hjsdp23213-asd212  Rack1
UN  192.0.0.45  299.9 GB   256          ?       c516as2a17c-4c73-2983hjsdp23213-asd212  Rack1
UN  192.0.0.46  290.96 GB  256          ?       2179as24b7d-4f7a-2983hjsdp23213-asd212  Rack1
Datacenter: dc3
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address          Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
DN  192.0.0.47    189.23 GB  256          ?       987aas27360-e981-2983hjsdp23213-asd212  Rack1
DN  192.0.0.48    224.67 GB  256          ?       d79cas20a27-3068-2983hjsdp23213-asd212  Rack1
DN  192.0.0.49    158.87 GB  256          ?       502bas280d5-2d5d-2983hjsdp23213-asd212  Rack1
DN  192.0.0.50    252.01 GB  256          ?       cd80as21422-e532-2983hjsdp23213-asd212  Rack1
```

I am already follow instruction from this https://docs.scylladb.com/operating-scylla/procedures/cluster-management/add-node-to-cluster/

Unfortunately,  all node in datacenter dc3  stop running for 3X24hours. After problem solve and  i started all node in dc3, all node in datacenter dc1 high load - and every transactions timeout.

Same case, **if i add new and fresh datacenter ( example dc2 )** - also dc1 high load and make all transactions timeout.

How to add new DC on running production without losing performance on existing node.
Thanks for your helps
How to start this dc3

Comment: Try follow https://docs.scylladb.com/operating-scylla/procedures/cluster-management/add-dc-to-existing-dc/

Comment: yes, we have follow this documentations - but not solved the problems. any clue fow add new node, with existing node still can produce for transactions ?

Comment: Adding a new DC will always cuase the existing DC(s) to show high loads due to the increased network traffic between DC's as data is being written to the newly started DC. What hardware or instances are you using and where are your DC's. Better yet add more details to your question such as how much data per node and instance/machine size ie vCPU count and mem size, replication factor and if possible copy paste the output of nodetool describecluster